# mysql_connect() is not getting to the correct server

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I have a system with a globally open mysql connection to the local server. In one of my files I am opening an additional connection to a remote machine.

Wieldly instead of trying to connect to that machine, I get an access denied message from my ISP (it seems to be trying to connect to the database on that machine).

I am trying to connect using:

`$cust_conn = mysql_connect($host,'root','##password##');`

I have tried `subdomain.domain.com:3306`, `subdomain.domain.com` and `ip:3306` as the value for `$host`.

The wierd this is the response i get:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'my.isp.com' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/report/module/sql_view.php on line 19 Error: Could not connect to database:
```

Any ideas why this would happen? It seems like for some reason my script is attempting to connect to my ISPs server, instead of the one passed in `$host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that hostname in the error (my.isp.com) is your client's host...remote root access is often disabled, or perhaps the pass/host combo is wrong

to add the creds:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Added a new user 'external' and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

The host given in the error message is the host it's trying to connect from, not to.